# Django UserCreationForm not Submitting

Tags: python, django

I have django site that is am currently trying to create a user creation form for. I have following all the steps but something is not happening. When I click the button in my register form it does not submit anything. I also do not see a POST message in the terminal. When I go to the admin portal I also do not see what I have submitted.

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import StudentCourses
from .forms import StudentCoursesForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

def registerPage(request):
    form = UserCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            form = UserCreationForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'Courses/register.html', context)
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Register</h3>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

    </form>
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your button inside your form tags?

Comment: You could have commented this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Register</h3>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**What have i changed:**

I put `<button type="submit">Register</button>` inside .